# How to morph a SVG diamond into a circle

Tags: html, svg, svg-morphing

I've recently been dipping my toe into SVGs and I'm currently trying to morph a diamond into a circle when the user hovers over it.

I found this tutorial over at [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/svg-shape-morphing-works/)

I've noticed that they're using points to do the animation however my SVG shapes are:

```
<circle cx="49.873" cy="50.155" r="49.845"/>
```

and

```
<rect x="15.211" y="14.798" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -20.8426 50.3112)" width="70.198" height="71.034"/>
```

Is there a way to do this? How would I get the points of these shapes so I could follow the CSS Tricks tutorial?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For those interested:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid red;"preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet">
   <rect id="shape2" rx="0" y="0" x="100" width="50" height="50" transform="rotate(45)">
      <animate begin="shape2.mouseover" attributeName="rx" dur="700ms" to="50%" fill="freeze"/>
      <animate begin="shape2.mouseout" attributeName="rx" dur="700ms" to="0" fill="freeze"/>
    </rect>
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4e71gra6/

Answer (score 0):

Extending the first answer by user1788364:

With saving square value of shape:

https://jsfiddle.net/HoretskiyDima/xfat6oc2/13/

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid red;"preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet">
  <rect id="shape2" rx="0" y="0" x="100" width="50" height="50" transform="rotate(45)">
        
     <!-- Making cirle from rectangle -->
     <animate begin="shape2.mouseover" attributeName="rx" dur="2000ms" to="50%" fill="freeze"/>
     <animate begin="shape2.mouseout" attributeName="rx" dur="325ms" to="0" fill="freeze"/>

     <!-- In order to save square value, we need bigger radius then rectangle -->
     <!-- S = width * height -->
     <!-- S = PI * r^2 -->
     <!-- d = r * 2 =  sqrt(S/PI) * 2 = 56 -->
     <animate begin="shape2.mouseover" attributeName="width" dur="375ms" to="56" fill="freeze"/>
     <animate begin="shape2.mouseout;370ms" attributeName="width" dur="675ms" to="50" fill="freeze"/>
     <animate begin="shape2.mouseover" attributeName="height" dur="375ms" to="56" fill="freeze"/>
     <animate begin="shape2.mouseout;370ms" attributeName="height" dur="675ms" to="50" fill="freeze"/>

     <!-- In order to pin shape center position on the screenm we need to move back on half of delta radius -->
     <!-- (56 - 50) / 2 = 3 -->
     <animate begin="shape2.mouseover" attributeName="x" dur="375ms" to="97" fill="freeze"/>
     <animate begin="shape2.mouseout" attributeName="x" dur="675ms" to="100" fill="freeze"/>
     <animate begin="shape2.mouseover" attributeName="y" dur="375ms" to="-3" fill="freeze"/>
     <animate begin="shape2.mouseout" attributeName="y" dur="675ms" to="0" fill="freeze"/>
     
     <!-- TODO: "rx" attribute animation timing working strange. -->
  </rect>
</svg>
```